# getArguments() form Bundle method Xamanrin

Tags: xamarin, bundle

Can you get all Bundle arguments in Xamarin like is the method Bundle.getArguments() in Android-Java. I am using fragments, so I need them in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle contains method:

```
Bundle.KeySet() : ICollection<string>
```

Then you can enumerate:

```
List<object> values = new List<object>();
foreach(var bundleKey in Bundle.KeySet()){
 values.Add(Bundle.Get(bundleKey ));
}
```